# how to order rows by nearest value in joined table

Tags: sql

I have $my_average=2.5 and I would like to display 4 rows nearest this value.
I mean in this case **row_id** 12,13 and 15,16

f.e

```
row_id  srednia wydział uid
1       -100     *       12
...      ...     ...    ...
12       -10     *        1
13       -2      *      111
14       2.5     *      107
15       4.4     *      109
16       82      *       87
17       -3      *      114
...      ...    ...     ...
200      100     *      116
```

The problem is that my table is joined from other tables :( Is it possible that in this query I order column srednia to get nearest value to $my_average=2.5?

```
SELECT t1.średnia AS srednia, t2.field_5_value AS wydział, t4.uid
FROM preferencje t1
JOIN node t4 ON t1.entity_id = t4.nid
JOIN field_data_field_5 t2 ON t2.entity_id = t1.entity_id
```

Comment: Specify the question! If you want records based on row_id then why are you trying to order by srednia? The 4 nearest should be the 4 that are closest, or the 2 preceding and the next 2?

Comment: The best way would be to get 2 preceding and the next 2 :) I have no idea how to order it when I have joined tables like in this SQL query

Comment: would it be okay to just get the row_ids between the target (14) - 2 and +2? basically, do you need to handle missing row_ids?

Comment: I would like to change variable $my_average and get always nearest rows. Is it possible?

Comment: The actual value of an autogen id is pointless, and should be considered random data - its value is the other rows it's connected to.  This is especially important when the values in the non-key columns changes, and should give different rows!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT t1.średnia AS srednia, t2.field_5_value AS wydział, t4.uid
FROM preferencje t1 JOIN
     node t4
     ON t1.entity_id = t4.nid JOIN
     field_data_field_5 t2
     ON t2.entity_id = t1.entity_id
ORDER BY abs(srednia - 2.5)
LIMIT 4;
```

The only issue is the `LIMIT 4`.  This varies by database.  It could be `TOP 4` in the `SELECT` clause.  Or `FETCH FIRST 4 ROWS ONLY`.  Or even something else.